# Is it possible to capture the PowerShell commands that are generated from Windows GUIs like IIS?

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I was reading *Learn Windows PowerShell 3 in a Month of Lunches* by Jones and Hicks and this passage from Chapter 1 caught my attention:

> Microsoft's goal for Windows PowerShell is to build 100% of a production's administrative functionality in the shell. Microsoft continues to build GUI consoles, but those consoles are executing PowerShell commands behind the scenes. That approach forces the company to make sure that every possible thing you can do with the product is accessible through the shell. If you need to automate a repetitive task or create a process that the GUI doesn't enable well, you can drop into the shell and take full control for yourself.
>
> A number of Microsoft products have already adopted this approach, including Exchange Server 2007 and 2010, SharePoint Server 2010, many of the System Center products, and many components of Windows itself. Going forward, more and more products and Windows components will follow this pattern. The latest version of Windows Server, which is where PowerShell v3 was introduced, is almost completely managed from PowerShell - or by a GUI sitting atop PowerShell. That's why you can't afford to ignore PowerShell - over the next few years, it'll become the basis for more and more administration.

I was wondering if it is possible to capture the PowerShell commands that are generated from Windows GUIs and tools like IIS? 
It would make it very easy to create automation scripts that way, and also help in learning PowerShell.

Comment: What GUI's are you talking about? IIS 8.0 Configuration Editor has a feature to generate PowerShell scripts, but you are asking like everything can be done through PowerShell.

Comment: Hi @mikez.
I was reading "Learn powershell in a month of lunches" and it states that from Win8 and Server2012 all GUI's will use powershell commands to execute tasks. I was hoping there was a way to capture these.

Comment: I added a quote from the book to give some context for your question. Please expand or clarify if there is something missing.

Comment: That is absolutely bang on @mikez, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick a Start-Transcript call in your all-host profile (`$Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts`), probably generating a filename for it based on date or counter or something.

Use something like [this Transcript module](http://www.powertheshell.com/transcript/) to add support first for hosts that don't normally allow it (ISE v4.0 and below, SharePoint, etc), possibly only including it if the host isn't PowerShell itself.